# How to transform detailed data to summary level?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am very new to using plsql to query Oracle. Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
Doctor  |  Patient  
A       |  John  
A       |  Amy  
B       |  Alex  
B       |  Jane  
B       |  Brian
```

How do I do a count on patient such that, the data will transform into:

```
Doctor  |  Count of Patient  
A       |  2  
B       |  3
```

I think the query should be something like:

```
select doctor, count(patient)
from table A
```

Comment: Answer is already provided, but I would suggest that you do a little research on the group by statement and it's uses as far as aggregation goes (count is an aggregation)

Comment: I agree with @Twelfth,  I couldnt find an immediate dupe, but i'm sure there is one.  Knowing that "group by" is what you need to search on perhaps is the key here.

Comment: @Twelfth I would like to count the records after the group by statement. I actually have multiple tables joined together with group by and where clause. Will this still work?

Comment: @paqogomez How do I make it such that it will only count after the group by statement? My query is actually so much more complicated than the one above

Comment: @Futochan, ah.. well then that sounds like a different question.  What do you mean "after the group by"?

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) of example data? and some expected output?

Comment: @Futochan - sorry, not understanding what you mean by 'after the group by'...counting is an aggregate function and requires the group by to function, so counting after the group by doesn't make the most sense.  You can create a subquery with an aggregate and then aggregate from that subquery if thats where you are going with this.

Comment: Without knowing more, I think @Twelfth is right on.  Create this portion of your query with a group by in a subquery.  Then join it to the main body of the more complicated query.

Comment: @paqogomez - best I can tell, he wants a count added to a larger query...so a subquery to get the count joined to whatever larger query he has should work.  I've added an answer to that extent.

Comment: @Twelfth I created a subquery to do the count and verified the result. Thank you everyone for the help.

Comment: @paqogomez Figured out the query. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

```
select
  doctor, count(*)
from
  tablea
group by doctor
```

Answer (score 2):

Entirely guessing here...psuedo code at best

```
select (columns), a.counter
from yourcurrentjoins
inner join (select
  doctor, count(*) as counter
  from
  tablea
  group by doctor) a
on yourcurrentjoin.doctor = a.doctor
```

This will allow you to refer to a.counter as a column in your select statement...preserves your original logic and all the columns you want while adding the count column you need.